Error trying to run a FAT binary on iOS device: incompatible architecture message while correct architecture is included
I've been trying to Google similar issues, but it seems I'm the only one so far, to my surprise ...
I am trying to build Tesseract for iOS. There's various build scripts online that I've tried, but encounter problems with each.
The problem I encounter is that when I try to load the static library an error occurs, namely the following:

dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2DE6EFD-1E15-4573-8110-E941FC1F0A83/Ocr.Demo.app/runtimes/ios-arm64/native/Ocr.xcframework/liblept-5.a, 0x0002): '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2DE6EFD-1E15-4573-8110-E941FC1F0A83/IronOcr.Demo.app/runtimes/ios-arm64/native/Ocr.xcframework/liblept-5.a' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))

This issue only happens on a iOS device, not on the iOS Simulator, all works fine there ...
I try to load this static library from MAUI (C# codebase), but I don't think the issue is related to the C# stuff.
What I find weird, is that whenever I use lipo on my machine, even using xcrun (which uses lipo from Xcode dev tools), it seems to always add the 0xCAFEBABE header, never 0xFEEDFACF which seems to be same as MH_MAGIC[_64] (see: https://iphonedev.wiki/Mach-O_File_Format). Is there some way I can force lipo to add the 0xFEEDFACF header? Or should lipo do this automatically depending on contents?
For reference, these are the various Tesseract OCR build projects that I've tried to use. The top one is probably the best one to try, as it has recent commits.
To check the header, can use lipo -detailed_info [file]

https://github.com/Akylas/TesseractBuild (run the script, all binaries get the 0xCAFEBABE header)
https://github.com/hexdreamer/tesseract-build (run the script, all binaries get the 0xCAFEBABE header)
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/4093#issuecomment-1609298899 (added directory src/build, included the script in this directory and ran it after running the autoconfigure stuff, got 0xCAFEBABE header on the resulting binaries)
https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS (all the binaries in TesseractOCR/lib include the 0xCAFEBABE header)

I'm using Xcode 14.3 dev tools to build the library, as compilation fails when trying to compile with Xcode 15 version of dev tools. If one wants to try using the Xcode 14.3 dev tools, remember that Xcode versions can be installed side by side and xcode-select can be used to set a Xcode.app/Contents/Developer directory to use for command line tools.
Maybe it's somehow related to the SDK tooling on my machines, but I did try to build both on an Intel iMac as well as a M2 MacBook, both with the same results.

Another thing to consider, maybe somehow there's a different issue at play here, and the error shown here is only a symptom, not the real cause, why these binaries won't load.


Does this answer your question? dynamically loading static library?

Partially it does. I guess I do need a .dylib then. I do believe when using a .dylib I will have another issue (some missing symbol regarding NEON extensions), but lets try to re-compile some stuff to a .dylib first ...
